# Getting error while publishing message on topic on clustered kafka server

Tags: java, stream, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka is running in 3 server in cluster mode.

I created topic (`testdemo`) by below command line,

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testdemo
```

I am publishing data by below producer property,

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "ip:9003");
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "ip1:9091, ip2:9092, ip3:9093");

props.put("producer.type", "async");
props.put("batch.size", "500");
props.put("compression.codec", "1");
props.put("compression.topic", topicName);
props.put("key.serializer", keySerializer);
props.put("value.serializer", ValueSerializer);
```

While publishing data in topic Getting below error,

```
 Error when sending message to topic testdemo with key: null, value: 9 bytes with error: 
 Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. 
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

Comment: Check the 'listeners' setting. Besides, metadata.broker.list is deprecated. Stick to use bootstrap.servers

Comment: @amethystic so here  need to use  metadata.broker.list? if answer is no than how balancing data within three server?

Comment: Firstly, do not use metadata.broker.list. Secondly, you could specify only a few servers for bootstrap.servers instead of all servers in the cluster, since they are used to find the cluster information. Kafka will connect to other brokers if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. How can I know if more data inserted into queue than it is dividing among server or not?

Comment: I highly recommend you read how the producer works before writing your own https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#theproducer In your particular case check that bootstrap.servers is correct because it looks like you have a typo. You can list all of the brokers there if you want. I recommend doing that because you only have three brokers to use. As for distributing work, you only have one partition for this topic so only one broker is going to serve messages from this topic at a time. Additionally, the replication factor of one means you don't have any backups of that one partition.